# How to make sure that properties and values get read?

Tags: javascript, graphql, reactjs

I am working with graphql.

My backend is finaly set and now im working on sending queries from my frontend to my backend.

Imagine this query:

```
{
    login(Email:"MyEmail", Password:"MyCoolPasswordHello")
  {token
  refreshToken}
}
```

I was thinking that I could try to make my queries reuasable in the frontend so I created a queries file and did this:

```
export enum QueryNames {
  login = 'login',
}

export const getQuery = (query: QueryNames, params: any): any => {
  const queries = {
    login: `{login(${params}){token refreshToken}}`,
  }[query];

  if (!queries) return {};

  return queries;
};

export const query = (queryName: QueryNames, params: any) => getQuery(queryName, params);
```

It gets called like this:

```
console.log(getQuery(QueryNames.login, { Email: "Hello", Password: "HelloPassword" }));
```

Result:

> {login([object Object]){token refreshToken}}

I could change my login to

```
export const getQuery = (query: QueryNames, params: any): any => {
  const queries = {
    login: `{login(Emai:${params.Email} Password: ${params.Password}){token refreshToken}}`,
  }[query];

  if (!queries) return {};

  return queries;
};
```

And then I get the desired result.

Is there a way of doing it so that my property names and values get read instead of me explicitly having to set `Email:` and `Password:` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

took me a while but solved it like this:

```
export const makeArray = (obj) => Array.from(Object.keys(obj), k => [`${k}`, obj[k]]);
```

and using it like this:

```
export const getQuery = (query: QueryNames, params: any): any => {
  const props = makeArray(params);

  // @ts-ignore
  // eslint-disable-next-line array-callback-return
  const funcParams = props.map(current => `${current[0]} : ${current[1]} `);

  const queries = {
    login: `mutation {login(${funcParams}){token refreshToken}}`,
  }[query];

  if (!queries) return {};

  return queries;
};
```